# What will be the time complexity of insertion if a queue is implemented using two stacks?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

A **Queue** could be implemented using two **Stacks**.

So what will be the time complexity for insertion and deletion in this queue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question seems to be not well-defined unless you're willing to assert that there is only one way to implement a queue using two stacks. While I realize there is an "obvious" way, the details of the implementation should be indicated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity for insertion is $O(1)$ while deletion is $O(n)$ (in the worst case) for a single operation. The amortized costs for both are $O(1)$ since having to delete $n$ elements from the queue still takes $O(n)$ time.

The above is assuming your implementation is one stack called In for inserting new elements to and one stack called Out from which we will retrieve elements for deletion. Since we only ever add new elements to In, we only need a single push() for insertion. This gives the above time cost. For deletions, if Out is empty, pop() everything from In and push() it to Out. Then pop() the top element to return. This is $O(n)$. If Out is not empty, just pop() its top element. This gives worst case $O(n)$ but amortized $O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks John for your response.
But from several technical interviews, I came to know that the complexity for both insertion and deletion are O(n).

So, John is there any way so that the insertion time complexity could be O(n)?

Comment: You can certainly make insertion time worse if you want to. Copy the entire Out stack back onto the In stack. This is not necessary though as if there are any elements left on the Out stack, they represent the first elements you need to retrieve. So you can just pop() without needing to copy back to In.